# How do I deal with identically named fields in the source database, differentiated only by label name?

Tags: variables, sas, naming

The database setup at my organisation is SQL tables copied onto our SAS server. The SQL tables were setup to run pre-programmed SQL queries, now SAS is the tool used. This however creates an issue with some tables having variables that are too long for SAS, but work in SQL. The label for the source variable is correct and not shortened.

```
The source table (in SQL Server) names:

Consolidated_Arrears_Vs_Portfolio_Balance_Ltd
Consolidated_Arrears_Vs_Portfolio_Balance_Pure

In SAS:

Consolidated_Arrears_Vs_Portfoli
Consolidated_Arrears_Vs_Portfoli

SAS Labels:

Consolidated_Arrears_Vs_Portfolio_Balance_Ltd
Consolidated_Arrears_Vs_Portfolio_Balance_Pure
```

So, how do I tell the difference in code between these two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help to show what's actually happening at the moment. It's not possible for a SAS data set to have two variables with the same name, so far as I know, so I assume that you haven't been able to create such a data set. Are you getting errors when trying? If you have two separate data sets with these variables in them, you can use a RENAME statement (or the RENAME data set option) to rename one or both of them.

Comment: How are you connecting to the SQL Server database?  Are you using a LIBNAME statement and letting SAS automatically convert your SAS code into SQL Server code to query the database?  Or are you using pass through SQL queries to run SQL Server code directly in the database?

Comment: Did you try 40 lashes with a wet noodle to the designer of that database?

Comment: You can have identical columns in the case of view.  You will see a WARNING when the view is realized and the other same named columns will be dropped.  Also possible there is `...Portfoli` and `...Portfol1` which look alike `I` for `1`

Comment: Hi, I'm so far leaning toward Tom's second option, although I question whether wet is the best option?  Technical questions: The data tables are automatically set up by our SAS administrator, so they exist in some form on the SAS server and when we open Enterprise Guide and go to Open>Data the sub-libraries are in the SASApp Library folder, no libname needed. When I click on properties for the library the following is stated: Engine: ODBC, Options: schema='dbo' ACCESS=READONLY DATASRC=LIVE_REP      I think the table is an SQL view.

Answer (score 1):

To use the data as native in SAS, one approach would be to write a macro to map the original SQL names (per label) to the corresponding new SAS names.  If the original table names got mangled as well you have a lot more issues.

Original SQL

```
select Abracadabra_Magical_Unity_Formation_SequenceId  from AMUF_Master
```

Replace with

```
select %nameFor(Abracadabra_Magical_Unity_Formation_SequenceId)  from AMUF_Master
```

The macro `%nameFor` would either do a dynamic lookup against the tables in the library, or perhaps better, when a static table design, create a fixed mapping table from a one time lookup

```
* presume SQL data now in libref MIGRATED;
* do once to get the variable metadata that includes LABEL and NAME;
proc sql;
  create table static.nameFor as
  select * from sashelp.vcolumn
  where libnames = 'MIGRATED';

* use as needed;
%macro nameFor(SQL_Name);
  %sysfunc(dosubl(select NAME from static.nameFor where LABEL="&SQL_Name"))       
%mend;
```

You could also use the `static.nameFor` to discover all the SQL names that got changed during migration.  Those would be `where name ne label`.

An automated approach would be to create a search and replace program that makes changes to a copy of the original SQL queries on-hand.

The search and replace would be either

- find `<long-named column>`, replace with `%nameFor(<long-named column>)` , or
- find `<long-named column>`, replace with `<migrated to SAS column name>`

The first replacement way adds noise.
The second way loses some of the original queries 'true-flavor'